# Best way to select data in tree-like table with fallback to default

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an application that needs parameters based on some fields. If the specific field is not found, the app should get the less-specific parameter value:

```
+----+-------+-------+------+--------------------------------------+
|PAR | ColA  | ColB  | ColC | value                                |
+----+-------+-------+------+--------------------------------------+
|Par1| *     | *     | *    | (this is the default value)  99      |
+----+-------+-------+------+--------------------------------------+
|Par1| ValA1 | *     | *    | (in case no valid ColB+ColC) 100     |
+----+-------+-------+------+--------------------------------------+
|Par1| ValA1 | ValB1 | *    | (in case no valid ColC)      200     |
+----+-------+-------+------+--------------------------------------+
|Par1| ValA1 | ValB1 | ValC1| (in case everything is specified) 333|
+----+-------+-------+------+--------------------------------------+
```

So a user requesting:

ValA1,ValB1,ValC1 for "Par1" -> would get "333"

while a user requesting:

ValA1,ValB1,ValX for "Par1" -> would get "200".

I can easily do it using a set of queries or UNION (looking for all the cols first, than looking for ColC='*', then with ColB='*' and ColC='*' and so on) but is there a better way?

Example:

```
select value from mytab where PAR='Par1' and ColA='ValA1' and ColB='ValB1' and ColC='ValC1' 
UNION
select value from mytab where PAR='Par1' and ColA='ValA1' and ColB='ValB1' and ColC='*' 
UNION
select value from mytab where PAR='Par1' and ColA='ValA1' and ColB='*' and ColC='*' 
UNION
select value from mytab where PAR='Par1' and ColA='*' and ColB='*' and ColC='*'
```

then get the "value" with the most columns != '*'

I'm using Postgresql but I'm open to use a different db if that would help.

Would [LTREE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ltree.html) help here?

**EDIT:** the table can be very large (millions of records). So selecting by "PAR" only can return a very large (mostly useless) result set and not be that fast as selecting the proper rows...

Comment: Can you add your own solution using `UNION` to the question?

Comment: @Spade done (not checked, but that's the main idea)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select value 
from mytab 
where PAR='Par1' 
ORDER BY
   CASE WHEN ColA='ValA1' and ColB='ValB1' and ColC='ValC1' THEN 0 else 1 END ASC,
   CASE WHEN ColA='ValA1' and ColB='ValB1' THEN 0 else 1 END ASC,
   CASE WHEN ColA='ValA1' THEN 0 else 1 END ASC
LIMIT 1
```

You can add ordering by expression and get top one.

UPDATE:

You can add to the WHERE section

```
AND (ColA='ValA1' or ColA='*')
AND (ColB='ValB1' or ColB='*')
AND (ColC='ValC1' or ColC='*')
```

or even more complicated case

```
AND (
   (ColA='ValA1' and ColB='ValB1' and ColC='ValC1')
   OR
   (ColA='ValA1' and ColB='ValB1' and ColC='*')
   OR
   (ColA='ValA1' and ColB='*' and ColC='*')
   OR
   (ColA='*' and ColB='*' and ColC='*')
)
```

Comment: neat solution to have the db do the algorithm part (returning the "optimal" row) but I guess it would be slow on a big table (see my edit) as it "filters" on the order by, so I think using only an index on "PAR" (and not on the other cols)?